# How do you make selectable text active once exported via Google Swiffy

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-2, google-swiffy

I've set the text as selectable on Flash, and exported it via google-swiffy into HTML5. However, once exported the selectable text is not longer selectable. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't export TextField with Swiffy from Flash, what you can do is exporting the flash as is and add on top of the swiffy output the fields. I use the following code for generating fields:

`function createForm() {
    var fields = new Array(
        { name: 'field1', left: 90, width: 135, height: 40 },
        { name: 'field2', left: 90, width: 135, height: 40 },
        { name: 'field3', left: 90, width: 135, height: 40 },
        { name: 'field4', left: 90, width: 135, height: 40 }
    );
    var top = 245;
    var tabIndex = 1;
    for( i in fields ) {
        var input = fields[i];
        var style = 'left:' + input.left + 
                    'px;width:' + input.width + 'px;height:' + 
                    input.height + 'px;top:' + top + 'px;';
        // Create left
        var html = '<input type="text" name="' + input.name + 
                    '" tabindex="' + tabIndex + '" style="' + style + '"/>';
        $("#form").append( html );
        top += 75;
    }
}`